# Unknown exception is thrown without inner exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

The following exception:

> Exception: An error occurred while executing the command definition.
>     See the inner exception for

and there is no inner exception.

Is thrown from the following **code** from the getter:

```
bool IsVerifyingPassword
{
    get
    {
        return (bool?)ViewState["IsDoubleCheckPassword"] ?? false;
    }
    set { ViewState["IsDoubleCheckPassword"] = value; }
}
```

Where's my fault?

Comment: Is it thrown from the getter or the setter?

Comment: Why would you want a nullable boolean? Either its true or false...

Comment: for indeterminite cases.

Comment: Really unclear what is the business case of indetermined IsVerifyingPassword, it makes logic more complex

Comment: @sllev &  @Rumplin: When the value isn't set then the view state variable will return `null`, so, in that case, I return false, which is the default value for undetermined case.

Comment: @French Boy: now this makes sense. In this case you do not need a nullable bool property IsVerifyingPassword, make it bool

Comment: @ sllev: Who said it's nullable? or I need it nullable?

Comment: @French Boy: from code you've posted you cast return value to nullable bool: return (bool?), really code you've provided should not coplile at all.

Comment: @sllev : No, it compiles well. The value which I want to set is boolean and casting to `bool?` is just for returning `false` in case the state variable isn't set yet.

Comment: @sellv: it matches the following: `if (ViewState["aKey"] == null) return false; else return (bool)ViewState["aKey"];`

Answer (score 2):

Try out:

```
bool IsVerifyingPassword
{
  get
  {
       bool returnValue = false;
       object viewStateValue = ViewState["IsDoubleCheckPassword"];           
       if (viewStateValue != null)
       {           
          // stay false if not able to retrieve bool from ViewState
          bool.TryParse(viewStateValue.ToString(), out returnValue);
       }

       return returnValue;
  }
```

If the property really should be nullable boolean then:

```
bool? IsVerifyingPassword
{
   get
   {
       object viewStateValue = ViewState["IsDoubleCheckPassword"];           
       if (viewStateValue != null)
       {
          bool returnValue = false;

          // stay false if not able to retrieve bool from ViewState
          bool.TryParse(viewStateValue.ToString(), out returnValue);
          return returnValue;
       }else
       {
          return null;
       } 
   }
```